# Managing several hundred occurrences of NSLocalizedString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, internationalization

My application has several hundred points of localisation, some of which can be reused many times. To prevent from hunting and pecking through code to find occurrences of a particular `NSLocalizedString`, I create a macro for each in a header file using the `#define` preprocessor directive. For example:

```
#define kLocFirstString  NSLocalizedString(@"Default Text", @"Comment")
#define kLocSecondString NSLocalizedString(@"More Text", @"Another comment")
...
```

When I want to refer to a particular string, I do so by its macro name. This method has been working nicely for me, but I'm concerned that such blatant abuse of `#define` is frowned upon. From the standpoint of "correctness", should I just inline each `NSLocalizedString` with the code, or is there another method (`extern NSString *aString;` perhaps?) that I can use to collect the declarations in one place?

Comment: Nothing wrong with using #define in this way. It's what it's meant for.

Comment: I guess I shouldn't have been so concerned after all! Thanks Jason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple provide the genstrings utility that can generate your strings file directly from the source code automatically.  This means you can probably just inline your NSLocalizedStrings.

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/genstrings.1.html

Comment: True, although there'd be a degree of repetition with a number of strings. My main concern was that my current implementation was against best practices, but Jason's response confirmed that it's ok.

Comment: Yes, I agree, there is nothing wrong with your original approach.  I tend to use the approach I described because it is as per the Apple guidelines.

NB genstrings is clever enough to remove repeated strings.